# How to write query to using 'Not'?

Tags: sql

I have to find list of UNIQUE users by user_group. User who has user_group as `Citrix_acc` should be in the list, user who has user_group as `REG_acc` should not be in the list.

Below is my query, can you tell me where it went wrong?

```
SELECT distinct *  
FROM usergroup_master 
WHERE user_group= 'Citrix_acc' not user_group='Reg_acc';
```

Comment: Would you mind telling us where it went wrong for you? You've probably ran it on some small set of data and found that some rows are not in the result set, while they should be. Or does your DB show some error?

Comment: Btw, I think you've missed the `AND` logical operator which should be used when you want two conditions to hold in `WHERE`.

Comment: Well the not condition isn't needed here, because you're already saying that the column must be equal to 'Citrix_acc'.

Comment: Do you mean that a user can have multiple groups but you only want to return those with `Citrix_acc`?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct * 
FROM usergroup_master 
WHERE user_group = 'Citrix_acc'
```

You don't really need a second part of the where clause. Since if the user_group = 'Citrix_acc' it can't also be = 'Reg_acc'. Assuming that *is* what you are looking for of course.

edit: To clarify how you would write the query if you *do* need an additional clause would be like this:

```
SELECT distinct * 
FROM usergroup_master 
WHERE user_group = 'Citrix_acc' AND SomeColumn <> 'SomeValue'
```

Comment: @Joe Honestly the more I stay on SO the more I am realizing that there are a lot of people who will downvote a correct answer because they a) don't like the question or b) want their own answer to be top.

Comment: @JacobH: or c) they don't understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to return all users who have a `user_group = 'Citrix_acc'` but they don't have another `user_group` associated with them like `Reg_acc`. You should be able to get the result you want by using a `NOT EXISTS` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
select distinct <UserId> -- or insert your column for user info
from usergroup_master m1
where m1.user_group = 'Citrix_ac'
  and not exists (select 1
                  from #usergroup_master m2
                  where m1.UserId = m2.UserId  -- assuming you have a user id column 
                    and m2.user_group = 'Reg_acc')
```

Here is a [small demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/668269) showing how this works.

You can't use your original version of the query because `user_group` can't have two values on the same row, so you need to perform some sort of operation to compare multiple rows for each user.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for *any* distinct usergroup, and just need to make sure that REG_acc doesn't get in, then all you need to do is eliminate REG_acc.

(I'm going to assume that REG is capitalized, like it is the first time you mention it; in the code you didn't capitalize.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM usergroup_master WHERE user_group <> 'REG_acc'
```

This will include any other usergroup, including Citrix.

If you only want Citrix:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM usergroup_master WHERE user_group = 'Citrix_acc'
```

Comment: After looking this back over, Jacob H's answer is better than mine. I don't have the rep to knock off the downvote, though.